How does Re-Planning technically work
I recently came across the topic of re-planning in the area of nurse rostering and was wondering how the whole thing works? For example, how is the absence of a nurse modeled or taken into account for re-planning? As new constraints or how? Or is a stochastic part integrated?

See: Gerald G. Brown, Robert F. Dell, R. Kevin Wood, (1997) Optimization and Persistence. Interfaces 27(5):15-37. https://doi.org/10.1287/inte.27.5.15

I don't think there is any single answer to this. There is a video of one example of continuous roster planning using OptaPlanner (now Timefold).
If we assume that an optimization model is used to generate an initial roster plan over a fixed time horizon (say times 0 to $T$), then a common approach to adjusting the plan at time $t>0$ is the following:

start with the same model;
either slide the horizon (making it $t$ to $T+t$) or compress the horizon ($t$ to $T$);
make any necessary changes to model parameters (for instance, the available working hours for nurse Ratched are adjusted to reflect hours already worked between 0 and $t$);
freeze any variable values from the previous solution that management deems unchangeable (e.g., the original solution gave nurse Jones a week off and it cannot be rescinded because she's taking vacation someplace far away);
keep any other variables from the time interval $[t, T]$ as variables (meaning they can change values from the previous solution); and
either optimize the original objective function over the new time horizon or minimize the cost of the changes being made (again, depending on management preference).


Yes - see also my newer shorts on Continuous Planning and Real-time Planning. And our documentation on this topic.
